# Bootstrap button group - overriding active/focus states

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I'm using a Bootstrap button group and having an issue overriding some CSS states. I believe the state is `:active:focus` that is adding a dark blue background to the button while it is in the act of being clicked, which I've tried overriding with no success.

I've provided a [Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/jer8k6ex/) replicating the issue I'm experiencing.

Attempting to override this style with:

```
.btn-group label.btn-primary:active:focus {
    background-color: #ffffff;
}
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: so idk why it doesnt work for `.btn-primary`, but if you switch it to `.btn-default` you can mess with the colors in the inspector: https://jsfiddle.net/jer8k6ex/3/

Comment: can you post snippet of your code?

Comment: @indubitablee that works, thanks. Strange how `.btn-default` is behaving different from `.btn-primary'

Comment: @PriyaPayyavula https://jsfiddle.net/jer8k6ex/

Comment: Oops! I did not see that.

Answer (score 0):

You cant chain those states together like that:

do them separately:

```
.btn-group label.btn-primary:active {
    background-color: #ffffff;
}

.btn-group label.btn-focus{
    background-color: #ffffff;
}
```

(btw i think you might want `transparent` and not `#ffffff`

https://jsfiddle.net/jer8k6ex/4/

Comment: you certainly can chain those states

Comment: @noclist when i was inspecting through, with your original css, it didnt overwrite the bootstrap `:active` code. but when I separated them (rather, just removed `:focus`), it worked as shown in the jsfiddle

Comment: @noclist, the bootstrap css also has them as two separate selectors. idk if you can or cant in general, but i do know that in the situation presented in your jsfiddle, that this is a testable solution